# vuejs inline editing with select box option call issues

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

Good Day, I'm working on a simple inline editing functionality with Vuejs. Please have a look at this [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/vevivesena/edit?html,js,output).

Users info. listed with `Edit` buttons, when clicked i turn those into input/select fields and populate corresponding options with helper methods.

My issue here is once i populate select options, my helper methods being called even if i change select value. How can i change this to load them only once and use them. Also, how can i validate current row fields as required when clicked on `save` button?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this.

```
  new Vue({
    el: '#app',

    data: {
      users: [
        {name: 'Jhon', city:'Newyork', country: 'US', country_id:'23', city_id:'4'},
        {name: 'Ali', city:'London', country: 'UK', country_id:'13', city_id:'33'},
        {name: 'Raj', city:'Delhi', country: 'IN', country_id:'3', city_id:'11'},
      ],
      cities: [
          {id:'4', val:'Newyork', country_id:'23'},
          {id:'33', val:'London', country_id:'13'},
          {id:'11', val:'Delhi', country_id:'3'},
         ],
      countries: [
          {id:'23', val:'US'},
          {id:'13', val:'UK'}, 
          {id:'3', val:'IN'}, 
        ]

    },
    computed:{
      citiesByCountry(){
        return this.countries.reduce((acc, country) => {
          acc[country.id] = this.cities.filter(c => c.country_id == country.id)
          return acc
        }, {})
      }
    },
    methods: {
      edit :function(obj){
        this.$set(obj, 'editmode', true);
      },
      save : function(obj){
        this.$set(obj, 'editmode', false);
      },
      cloneLast:function(){
        var lastObj = this.users[this.users.length-1];
        lastObj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(lastObj));
        lastObj.editmode = true;
        this.users.push(lastObj);
      },

    }
  })
```

And change your template to this.

```
  <td>
    <span v-if="user.editmode">
      <select v-model="user.city_id" required>
        <option v-for="option in citiesByCountry[user.country_id]" :value="option.id">{{option.val}}</option>
      </select>  
    </span>
    <span v-else>{{user.city}}</span>
  </td>
  <td>
    <span v-if="user.editmode">

      <select v-model="user.country_id" required>
        <option v-for="option in countries" :value="option.id">{{option.val}}</option>
      </select>
    </span>
    <span v-else>{{user.country}}</span>
  </td>
```

Working [example](http://jsbin.com/jakahohura/1/edit?html,js,output).

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. However, in reality the city options are dependent on country chosen. It will send out ajax request to server to get the city list. I can not store them as static object. Sorry, for not being clear.

Comment: @NareshRevoori then make it a computed.

Comment: can i pass params to computed method?

Comment: Awesome, thank you so much. Just one last thing how can i update the selected value into country and city fields.. they are not updating after clicking on save btn.

Comment: i know i'm not binding on country and city props but on country_id and city_id.. just wana know to how to update them with selected vals.

Comment: @NareshRevoori it depends. On the user, do you want to store the city ID or the name? It seems like you should use the ID.

Comment: @NareshRevoori For example. http://jsbin.com/caneqejohi/edit?html,js,output

Comment: i cant thank you enough, you saved my day. i will take it from here.

Comment: how can make them as required, a red border around fields upon clicking save with out info? sorry if im asking too many qns.

Comment: @NareshRevoori When you click save, check to see if you have valid values. If they aren't valid, prevent the mode change and do any highlighting you want.

Comment: i just though so, but city_id still set to old val when country is changed.

Comment: @NareshRevoori clear the city when the country changes.